# Doing FFT calculations with FFTW_MEASURE gives wrong results, compared with FFTW_ESTIMATE

Tags: c++, armadillo, fftw

I would like to apply a 1d-FFT to each row of my complex matrix, created in Armadillo. For that, I can either use the built-in function or use FFTW. For that I wrote a short test program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <arrayfire.h>
#include <armadillo>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <complex>
#include <fftw3.h>

constexpr int matrix_size = 1024;
constexpr int bench_rounds = 10;

#define USE_ESTIMATE

arma::cx_mat arma_fft(const arma::cx_mat &in_mat){
    arma::cx_mat ret_mat(in_mat.n_cols, in_mat.n_rows, arma::fill::zeros);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in_mat.n_rows; ++i)
        ret_mat.row(i) = arma::fft(in_mat.row(i));
    return ret_mat;
}

arma::cx_mat arma_ifft(const arma::cx_mat &in_mat){
    arma::cx_mat ret_mat(in_mat.n_cols, in_mat.n_rows, arma::fill::zeros);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in_mat.n_rows; ++i)
        ret_mat.row(i) = arma::ifft(in_mat.row(i));
    return ret_mat;
}

#ifndef USE_ESTIMATE
arma::cx_mat fftw_fft(const arma::cx_mat &in_mat){
    fftw_plan p;
    arma::cx_mat ret_mat(in_mat.n_cols, in_mat.n_rows, arma::fill::zeros);
    arma::cx_rowvec temp_vec = in_mat.row(0);
    arma::cx_rowvec out_vec(temp_vec.size(), arma::fill::zeros);
    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d (matrix_size,
                          (fftw_complex*)temp_vec.memptr(),
                          (fftw_complex*)out_vec.memptr(),
                          FFTW_FORWARD,
                          FFTW_MEASURE);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in_mat.n_rows; ++i){
        temp_vec = in_mat.row(i);
        out_vec = arma::cx_rowvec(temp_vec.size(), arma::fill::zeros);

        fftw_execute (p);

        ret_mat.row(i) = out_vec;
    }
    fftw_destroy_plan (p);
    return ret_mat;
}

arma::cx_mat fftw_ifft(const arma::cx_mat &in_mat){
    fftw_plan p;
    arma::cx_mat ret_mat(in_mat.n_cols, in_mat.n_rows, arma::fill::zeros);
    arma::cx_rowvec temp_vec = in_mat.row(0);
    arma::cx_rowvec out_vec(temp_vec.size(), arma::fill::zeros);
    p = fftw_plan_dft_1d (matrix_size,
                          (fftw_complex*)temp_vec.memptr(),
                          (fftw_complex*)out_vec.memptr(),
                          FFTW_BACKWARD,
                          FFTW_MEASURE);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in_mat.n_rows; ++i){
        temp_vec = in_mat.row(i);
        out_vec = arma::cx_rowvec(temp_vec.size(), arma::fill::zeros);

        fftw_execute (p);

        ret_mat.row(i) = out_vec;
    }
    fftw_destroy_plan (p);
    return ret_mat / matrix_size;
}
#else
arma::cx_mat fftw_fft(const arma::cx_mat &in_mat){
    fftw_plan p;
    arma::cx_mat ret_mat(in_mat.n_cols, in_mat.n_rows, arma::fill::zeros);
    arma::cx_rowvec temp_vec = in_mat.row(0);
    arma::cx_rowvec out_vec(temp_vec.size(), arma::fill::zeros);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < in_mat.n_rows; ++i){
        temp_vec = in_mat.row(i);
        out_vec = arma::cx_rowvec(temp_vec.size(), arma::fill::zeros);

        p = fftw_plan_dft_1d (matrix_size,
                              (fftw_complex*)temp_vec.memptr(),
                              (fftw_complex*)out_vec.memptr(),
                              FFTW_FORWARD,
                              FFTW_ESTIMATE);

        fftw_execute (p);

        ret_mat.row(i) = out_vec;
    }
    fftw_destroy_plan (p);
    return ret_mat;
}

arma::cx_mat fftw_ifft(const arma::cx_mat &in_mat){
    fftw_plan p;
    arma::cx_mat ret_mat(in_mat.n_cols, in_mat.n_rows, arma::fill::zeros);
    arma::cx_rowvec temp_vec = in_mat.row(0);
    for(size_t i = 0; i < in_mat.n_rows; ++i){
        temp_vec = in_mat.row(i);
        arma::cx_rowvec out_vec = arma::cx_rowvec(temp_vec.size(), arma::fill::zeros);
        p = fftw_plan_dft_1d (matrix_size,
                              (fftw_complex*)temp_vec.memptr(),
                              (fftw_complex*)out_vec.memptr(),
                              FFTW_BACKWARD,
                              FFTW_ESTIMATE);
        fftw_execute (p);

        ret_mat.row(i) = out_vec;
    }
    fftw_destroy_plan (p);
    return ret_mat / matrix_size;
}
#endif
int main()
{
    //Check correctness
    arma::cx_mat test_mat = arma::randu<arma::cx_mat>(matrix_size, matrix_size);
    arma::cx_mat fft_test_mat = arma_fft(test_mat);
    arma::cx_mat fftw_test_mat = fftw_fft (test_mat);
    arma::cx_mat ifft_test_mat = arma_ifft(fft_test_mat);
    arma::cx_mat ifftw_test_mat = fftw_ifft (fftw_test_mat);
    std::cout << "Input and output for arma are equal: " << arma::approx_equal(test_mat, ifft_test_mat, "rel_tol", 0.01) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Forward output for arma and fftw are equal: " << arma::approx_equal(fft_test_mat, fftw_test_mat, "rel_tol", 0.01) << '\n';
    std::cout << "Output for arma and fftw are equal: " << arma::approx_equal(ifftw_test_mat, ifft_test_mat, "rel_tol", 0.01) << '\n';
}
```

When using `FFTW_ESTIMATE`, my results are equal. When using `FFTW_MEASURE` for a higher processing speed, my results are wrong, and approximately half of the resulting fftw-matrix is zero. Why? Did I forget something here?

Comment: FFTW can overwrite the arrays when making the plans when FFTW_MEASURE is used. Thus the data is overwritten and probably put to zero when the plan is made. Try to set the data after making the plan.

Comment: I'm doing that already, I fill temp_vec in the loop, and initialize the plan before that loop

Comment: Ah sorry I mixed up the two methods. Then the problem is likely that you recreate the out_vector in the loops. I don't know how armadillo works, but if this step does reallocations then it will fail. You don't need to clear the output for FFTW. If I remove ( out_vec = arma::cx_rowvec ) in the two loops then it works.